# Exchange hybrid migration wizard for Windows Server 2008

Tags: exchange

I am trying to install the hybrid migration wizard on a first release windows 2008 server and I am at a point were it needs .NET 4.7 which will not install.  Does anyone have a workaround for this?  Microsoft compatibility matrix did say it was supported but they may have changed things.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found out that the Hybrid Configuration Wizard does not have to be run on the exchange server.  I ran it from a Windows 10 Desktop and it setup the hybrid config and transferred my test batch of mailboxes.   So if you are going from a Windows Server 2008 first release with Exchange 2010, your best bet is to install the wizard on a workstation of another server.

kevin

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2008 SP2 or later and Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.2 or later are required to install Hybrid Configuration Wizard. For your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/plan-and-deploy/supportability-matrix?view=exchserver-2019#supported-active-directory-environments

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/hybrid-deployment-prerequisites#prerequisites-for-hybrid-deployment